# What is the relationship between Odin, Seifer, and the kanji that appears?

Tags: japanese-language, final-fantasy

In *Final Fantasy VIII*, if you have the Odin GF (I don't know if this still happens if you don't have him, I always got him), Odin appears when you fight Seifer at the end of Disk 3. Generally, when this happens, he comes in with Zantetsuken and kills all the enemies, never works in a boss battle except in this scripted sequence where Seifer kills Odin.

When Odin appears and kills enemies, there are 3 kanji that appear, each one appearing by itself as the scene of the strike is replied. But when Seifer kills Odin, there is a fourth Kanji while Gilgamesh (who also uses Zantetsuken, replacing Odin) shows nothing.

So I wonder, what is the relationship between Odin, Seifer, and the kanji that appears when they attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kanji that appears when Odin uses his special attack is [**斬鉄剣**](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%96%AC%E9%89%84%E5%89%A3) (*Zantetsuken*).

However, when Seifer kills Odin, it shows **斬鉄剣**[**返し**](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97) (*Zantetsuken-gaeshi*) which literally means "Zantetsuken Reversal". *-(k/g)aeshi* is a common suffix to mean "reversal/counter", especially in martial arts like [Judo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_judo_techniques) (e.g. [*Tsubame-gaeshi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsubame_gaeshi)).